# Yii not returning is null value from db

Tags: php, yii

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `USER` = '1599' AND `id` = '124253' AND `wednesday` IS NULL
```

This is the php code:

```
$check = Test::model()->find("id =:id and user =:user and ".$day." =:day ", array(":id" => $check_lunch_per_day, ":user" => $user, 'day'=> null));
```

another try:

```
$check = Test::model()->find("id =:id and user =:user and ".$day." =:day ", array(":id" => $check_lunch_per_day, ":user" => $user, 'day'=> 'IS NULL'));
```

But the result of the check is always null. What should I do? I want to get the wednesday column value if it is null.

Comment: You have a column called "wednesday"? Or called "day"

Comment: You have a missing colon in the param array `day` should be `:day`

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

setting `:day` to `IS NULL`

```
    $check = Test::model()->find("id =:id and user =:user and ".$day." =:day ",
array(":id" => $check_lunch_per_day, ":user" => $user, ':day'=> 'IS NULL'));
```